# update statement Java sql exception: Too few parameters expected one more

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, jdbc, odbc

So I have a method for updating some fields in a MS Access 2007 table, and whenever I try to update I get the following exception:
    java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters.   Expected 11.
It always shows that one more is expected than there are in the query.

The code of the method is:

```
try {
        String upit = "UPDATE Izlagac SET NazivIzlagaca=?, PIB=?, Telefon=?, "
                + " KontaktOsoba=?, Email=?, TipIzlagaca=?, Ulica=?, Broj=?, Mesto=?, Drzava=? WHERE "
                + " SifraIzlagaca = " + i.getSifraIzlagaca() + ";";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(upit);
        pstmt.setString(1, i.getNazivIzlagaca());
        pstmt.setString(2, i.getPIB());
        pstmt.setString(3, i.getTelefon());
        pstmt.setString(4, i.getKontaktOsoba());
        pstmt.setString(5, i.getEmail());
        pstmt.setString(6, i.getTipIzlagaca());
        pstmt.setString(7, i.getUlica());
        pstmt.setString(8, i.getBroj());
        pstmt.setString(9, i.getMesto());
        pstmt.setString(10, i.getDrzava());
        System.out.println(pstmt.toString());
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        pstmt.close();
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DBBroker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return false;
    }
```

I am not using aliases so that doesn't seem to be the reason why the driver would expect additional parameter. All the column names are correctly spelled, triple checked it.

Comment: `i.getSifraIzlagaca()` does not happen to return a question mark, right?

Comment: No, it returns a normal string and the correct value.

Comment: Why not use `... WHERE SifraIzlagaca = ?` and `pstmt.setString(11, i.getSifraIzlagaca());` ?

Comment: I don't see i.getSifraIzlagaca() is actually wrapped within quotes! Never used MS Access, but aren't string parameters supposed to be quoted in standard SQL ?

Comment: Anirban Basak, yes it isn't but when you do wrap it, it throws a data mistype exception. 
Gord, thank you, it works now, it is a simple and elegant solution, I'll do that from now on.. :)
Although it should work this way too, but that's the evil Microsoft driver :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use string concatenation to build the WHERE clause; parameters are just as valid there as they are in the other parts of the PreparedStatement. So, just use

```java
String upit = "UPDATE Izlagac SET NazivIzlagaca=?, PIB=?, Telefon=?, "
        + " KontaktOsoba=?, Email=?, TipIzlagaca=?, Ulica=?, Broj=?, Mesto=?, Drzava=? WHERE "
        + " SifraIzlagaca=?";
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(upit);
pstmt.setString(1, i.getNazivIzlagaca());
pstmt.setString(2, i.getPIB());
pstmt.setString(3, i.getTelefon());
pstmt.setString(4, i.getKontaktOsoba());
pstmt.setString(5, i.getEmail());
pstmt.setString(6, i.getTipIzlagaca());
pstmt.setString(7, i.getUlica());
pstmt.setString(8, i.getBroj());
pstmt.setString(9, i.getMesto());
pstmt.setString(10, i.getDrzava());
pstmt.setString(11, i.getSifraIzlagaca());
```

Comment: yes, I realized that, after the comments above, and corrected it, it works fine now, thank you :)